# .NET Maui view left truncated on physical device not on simulator same model

Tags: ios, .net, maui

I have a xaml page that renders as expected on a simulator for iPhone iOS 16.4.   However on the physical device the grid looks like it has a margin="-15,0".   This does not happen on the main page but does to two subsequent pages that I push on the stack.  Going to different tabs it does not have this problem.   Any ideas what may be going on here?  This is only an iOS problem same app on android looks similar across simulator and physical device.

Simulator on left physical device on the right.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlCVI.png)

I tried this on android as well and it did not have the same problem.   I tried it on a couple of simulators and all simulator models appear as expected.   It's the iPhone 12pro physical device that appears off on two pages.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    x:Class="MyNextBook.Views.NewSeries"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:dxcv="clr-namespace:DevExpress.Maui.CollectionView;assembly=DevExpress.Maui.CollectionView"
    xmlns:fonts="clr-namespace:MyNextBook.Helpers"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNextBook.ViewModels"
    xmlns:popup="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.Maui.Popup;assembly=Syncfusion.Maui.Popup"
    xmlns:progressBar="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.Maui.ProgressBar;assembly=Syncfusion.Maui.ProgressBar"
    xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MyNextBook.Views"
    Title="Add New Series"
    BackgroundColor="{StaticResource AppBackgroundColor}">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:NewSeriesViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>


    <ContentPage.Behaviors>
        <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior Command="{Binding AppearingCommand}" EventName="Appearing" />
    </ContentPage.Behaviors>

    <ContentPage.Content>


        <Grid
            ColumnDefinitions="*,40"
            HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
            RowDefinitions="40,40,*,40">
            <views:HintPopup HintPreference="HintNewSeries" />


            <!--
            <SearchBar
                x:Name="newSeriesSearchBar"
                Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                Margin="0,0,3,0"
                toolkit:SetFocusOnEntryCompletedBehavior.NextElement="{x:Reference labelDisplay}"
                BackgroundColor="White"
                CancelButtonColor="Black"
                HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                IsTextPredictionEnabled="True"
                Placeholder="Character, Author, or search term..."

                SearchCommand="{Binding PerformSearchCommand}"
                SearchCommandParameter="{Binding Text, Source={x:Reference newSeriesSearchBar}}"
                TextColor="Black"
                WidthRequest="{Binding DeviceWidth}" />
            -->
            <SearchBar
                x:Name="newSeriesSearchBar"
                       Grid.Row="0"
                       Grid.Column="0"
                       Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                       BackgroundColor="White"
                     
                       CancelButtonColor="Black"
                       TextColor="Black"
                       Placeholder="Character, Author, or search term..."
                       SearchCommand="{Binding PerformSearchCommand}"
                SearchCommandParameter="{Binding Text, Source={x:Reference newSeriesSearchBar}}" />
            <Label
                x:Name="labelDisplay"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Grid.Column=" 0"
                Margin="15,0,0,0"
                FontAttributes="None"
                FontSize="Small"
                HorizontalOptions="Start"
                HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                IsVisible="{Binding DisplayCount}"
                Text="{Binding Path=ItemCount, StringFormat='{0} series found.'}"
                TextColor="{StaticResource AppPrimaryColor}"
                VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
            <ActivityIndicator
                Grid.Row="3"
                Grid.Column="1"
                HeightRequest="30"
                HorizontalOptions="End"
                IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}"
                VerticalOptions="Start"
                WidthRequest="30"
                ZIndex="9"
                Color="{x:StaticResource TertiaryColor}" />


            <Button
                Grid.Row="3"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                BackgroundColor="{StaticResource AppContentBackgroundColor}"
                Command="{Binding CreateFromScratchCommand}"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                Text="Create your own series?"
                TextColor="{StaticResource AppPrimaryColor}" />



            <dxcv:DXCollectionView
                x:Name="addSeriesList"
                Grid.Row="2"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                Margin="0,0,0,0"
                BackgroundColor="{x:StaticResource AppBackgroundColor}"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Items, Mode=TwoWay}"
                SelectionMode="None">


                <dxcv:DXCollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Frame
                            Margin="3,0,7,3"
                            BackgroundColor="{StaticResource AppBackgroundColor}"
                            BorderColor="{StaticResource AppContentBackgroundColor}">


                            <VerticalStackLayout>


                                <ImageButton
                                    Grid.Row="0"
                                    Grid.Column="1"
                                    Margin="0,1,0,0"
                                    Command="{Binding BindingContext.PerformAddSeriesCommand, Source={x:Reference Name=addSeriesList}}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                    HeightRequest="30"
                                    HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                                   
                                    VerticalOptions="Start"
                                    WidthRequest="30"
                                    ZIndex="2">
                                    <ImageButton.Source>
                                        <FontImageSource
                                            FontFamily="MD"
                                            Glyph="{x:Static fonts:IconFont.PlusBox}"
                                            Size="20"
                                            Color="{x:StaticResource TertiaryColor}" />
                                    </ImageButton.Source>
                                </ImageButton>

                                <Label
                                    Grid.Row="0"
                                    Grid.Column="0"
                                    Margin="5,0"
                                    FontAttributes="None"
                                    FontSize="Large"
                                    HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                                    Text="{Binding Name}"
                                    TextColor="{StaticResource AppPrimaryColor}"
                                    VerticalOptions="Start" />

                                <Frame
                                    Grid.Row="1"
                                    Grid.Column="0"
                                    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                    Margin="5,0,10,0"
                                    BackgroundColor="{StaticResource AppBackgroundColor}"
                                    BorderColor="{StaticResource AppBackgroundColor}"
                                    IsVisible="True"
                                    ZIndex="4">

                                    <Label
                                        x:Name="ShortDesc"
                                        Grid.Row="1"
                                        Grid.Column="0"
                                        Grid.ColumnSpan="1"
                                        Margin="5,0,20,5"
                                        HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                                        IsVisible="True"
                                        LineBreakMode="WordWrap"
                                        MaxLines="25"
                                        TextColor="{StaticResource AppPrimaryColor}"
                                        ZIndex="9">
                                        <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding BindingContext.ShowMoreOrLessCommand, Source={x:Reference Name=addSeriesList}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />

                                        </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <Label.FormattedText>
                                            <FormattedString>
                                                <Span Text="{Binding DisplayDesc}" />
                                                <Span
                                                    Text="{Binding MoreOrLess}"
                                                    TextColor="{StaticResource TertiaryColor}"
                                                    TextDecorations="Underline">
                                                    <Span.GestureRecognizers />
                                                </Span>

                                                <Span Text="." />

                                            </FormattedString>
                                        </Label.FormattedText>
                                    </Label>

                                </Frame>




                            </VerticalStackLayout>

                        </Frame>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </dxcv:DXCollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </dxcv:DXCollectionView>
        </Grid>

    </ContentPage.Content>

</ContentPage>
```

Comment: where is the relevant code?

Comment: I have edited the description to include the XAML for the page that is manifesting the problem.